# concat parts of a tuple to sensible date/time format

Tags: python, date, time, tuples

I'm trying to learn Python by getting simple things done in this language. I have a very simple log file:

```
LOGON, Thu 30-01-2014, 12:38:01,11, username1, machinename 
LOGOFF, Thu 30-01-2014, 12:56:41,57, username2, machinename 
LOGON, Thu 30-01-2014, 13:02:37,00, username3, machinename 
LOGOFF, Thu 30-01-2014, 13:02:51,48, username1, machinename 
LOGON, Thu 30-01-2014, 13:15:13,91, username2, machinename 
LOGOFF, Thu 30-01-2014, 14:58:31,38, username3, machinename 
LOGON, Thu 30-01-2014, 15:24:24,27, username2, machinename 
LOGOFF, Thu 30-01-2014, 15:48:31,87, username3, machinename
```

I open the file, and create a tuple:

```
# Open file, put it in a tuple
v_log_filename = 'test.txt'
with open(v_log_filename) as inputFile:
    t_log_lines = [tuple(line.split(',')) for line in inputFile.readlines()]
#Rearange output
for log in t_log_lines:
    print log[0],log[4],log[1],log[2]
```

Question:
I'd like to concat log[1] and log[2] to a sensible formated date and time, then recreate the tuple.

First try:

```
for log in t_log_lines:
    t_n_log_lines = t_n_log_lines + (log[0], log[4], (str(log[1]), str(log[2])))

for log in t_n_log_lines:
    print log
```

Result:

```
(' Thu 30-01-2014', ' 13:01:03')
LOGOFF
 username
(' Thu 30-01-2014', ' 13:01:35')
LOGON
 username
(' Thu 30-01-2014', ' 13:04:43')
LOGOFF
 username
(' Thu 30-01-2014', ' 13:04:59')
```

I'm looking for a solution more like:

```
('Thu 30-01-2014 13:01:03', 'LOGOFF', 'username')
```

Comment: Please define 'a sensible formated date and time'.

Comment: You need look at [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime).

Comment: @LutzHorn con catting log[1] and log[2] would be a start. Then I can pass that to datetime.datetime.strptime like Burhan Khalid suggested.

Comment: Thank you for all the suggestions. I consider this one answered!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives you exactly what you asked for:

```
t_n_log_lines = []
with open(v_log_filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        l = map(str.strip, line.split(','))
        t_n_log_lines.append((l[1] + ' ' + l[2], l[0], l[4]))

print t_n_log_lines
>>> [('Thu 30-01-2014 12:38:01', 'LOGON', 'username1'),
>>>  ('Thu 30-01-2014 12:56:41', 'LOGOFF', 'username2'),
>>>  ('Thu 30-01-2014 13:02:37', 'LOGON', 'username3'),
>>>  ('Thu 30-01-2014 13:02:51', 'LOGOFF', 'username1'),
>>>  ('Thu 30-01-2014 13:15:13', 'LOGON', 'username2'),
>>>  ('Thu 30-01-2014 14:58:31', 'LOGOFF', 'username3'),
>>>  ('Thu 30-01-2014 15:24:24', 'LOGON', 'username2'),
>>>  ('Thu 30-01-2014 15:48:31', 'LOGOFF', 'username3')]
```

The `log[n]` entries are already strings, so no need to convert them again. When you want to concatenate them together, use the `+` operator. When using `,`, python creates another tuple, which gets placed in the outer tuple. This is what you see in your output.

Comment: I updated the answer, now it gives a complete solution and should match exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you need this.

```
a=r'''LOGON, Thu 30-01-2014, 12:38:01,11, username1, machinename 
LOGOFF, Thu 30-01-2014, 12:56:41,57, username2, machinename 
LOGON, Thu 30-01-2014, 13:02:37,00, username3, machinename 
LOGOFF, Thu 30-01-2014, 13:02:51,48, username1, machinename 
LOGON, Thu 30-01-2014, 13:15:13,91, username2, machinename 
LOGOFF, Thu 30-01-2014, 14:58:31,38, username3, machinename 
LOGON, Thu 30-01-2014, 15:24:24,27, username2, machinename 
LOGOFF, Thu 30-01-2014, 15:48:31,87, username3, machinename'''

t_log_lines = [tuple(line.split(',')) for line in a.split('\n')]
t_n_log_lines=[]

for log in t_log_lines:
    log=map(lambda x: x.strip(),log)
    t_n_log_lines.append(  ("%s %s"%(log[1],log[2]), log[0],log[4],) ) 

for log in t_n_log_lines:
    print log
```

Comment: Yes, works too! Seems more elaborate than Michaels' suggestion. What does log=map(lambda x: x.strip(),log) do?

Comment: Lambda creates a function. String.strip() removes the white characters  at the beginning or the end of a string.